# Julia extension in VSCode does not update workspace and instead executes a 'task'

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, vscode-tasks

I have been using Julia on VSCode using its Julia extension.
I forgot since when, but pressing the triangle button in the upper right corresponding to "Julia: Run file in new process" does not end up in the Julia extension recognizing the output. For example, if I run the following julia code:

```
x = 1
```

A new 'task' is executed but the workspace in the left pane remains empty! I have never seen this 'task' thing before[image]. I am attaching a screenshot.

I have tried reinstalling Julia, VSCode, the Julia extension, but it seems not to work.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What if you put the cursor on the line of code and hit ctrl+enter ?

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it is working perfectly. Do you happen to know what I should do if I wanted to run the whole code other than selecting the whole code and pressing ctrl+enter?

Comment: It turned out that alt+enter runs the whole code, as can be seen in the [documentation](https://www.julia-vscode.org/docs/dev/userguide/keybindings/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using VSCode for julia programming for almost nine months, and I didn't use the triangle you mentioned even once. But, maybe it would be better to open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode) to notify the dev if it hasn't been already.
However, you can use another way to achieve your primary goal: Put the cursor on a line and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will leads to running the line in the REPL. If you would like to run the line and automatically move the cursor to the next line, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
In order to run just the selected line(s), you can select the line(s) you want using your mouse and then hit the keys mentioned above.
**Note that** if you select just a piece of a line and use one of the keyboard shortcuts mentioned above, it will lead to running just the chosen piece, not the entire line!